# Changes in Google websearch results

Tags: google-search

Just a few days ago, the first result I got when I searched "Napoleon" was this...

> Napoleon - ***Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia***
>
> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon

But suddenly, I started getting this...

> Napoleon
>
> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon

The difference is the bold part....What do you think is going on? Have I mistakenly fiddled with some button or other?

Comment: Google Websearch could depend on some algorithm or the page rank by which it will display may be that factors i think.

Answer (score 1):

The results displayed by Google Websearch could depend on several factors, including but not limited to:

- Google is running a test just for certain users.
- Internet connection speed
- Browser (change in version or the version become unsupported)
- Extensions, add-ons, plug-ins, etc.

Things to try:

- Use your current browser in private navigation mode
- Use a different browser
- Check for updates for your browser